# Frattini subgroup of p-groups characteristics

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, p-groups, maximal-subgroup, frattini-subgroup

"Assume $P$ is a $p$-group and $N$ is normal in $P$ with this property that $P/N$ is an abelian elementary group. Prove that $\Phi(P)$ is in $N$.
(*Note*: $\Phi(P)$ is intersection of maximal subgroups of $P$)"

I am going to bring my proof, which I am not sure about it.
**Lemma 1:** every finite abelian $p-$groups are in the form of $ G=Z_p \times \dots \times Z_p$.
*Proof:* We assume that $|G|=p^n$. By using induction, and the fact that each abelian group can be written as form of  $ G=Z_{p^{k1}}\times \dots \times Z_{p^{ki}}$. If the group is cyclic then it should be $G=Z_p$.(each element should have the same order $p$ in elementary $p-$groups) So, we can assume it is not cyclic and each of $p^{ki}<p^{n}$, and this means that we have the induction assumption on them. Thus, we will reach the result. We need to check that the lemma is true for $|P|=p$ and $|P|=p^2$. We know that each $p^2$ groups are the form of $Z_{p^2}$ or $Z_{p} \times Z_{p} $. But, the cyclic form is not possible as it is an elementary group.

**Lemma 2**: if $G$ an abelian elementary group with the order of more than $p^2$, then its Frattini subgroup is $1$.
*Proof*: Each elementary group is in the form of $ G=Z_p \times \dots \times Z_p$(by using Lemma1). I was thinking that if we drop one of $Z_p$ then the remaining will be a maximal subgroup in the $G$(Am I right here???). Thus, their intersection will be 1, and $G$ has a trivial Frattini subgroup.

Now we consider $G=P/N$, and it is an abelian elementary group. if $|P/N|=p$ then $N$ itself is a maximal subgroup in $P$, and from the definition the $\Phi(P)$ is in the $N$. So, we can assume that $|P/N| \ge p$. Now we want to assume that $\Phi(P)$ is not fully in $N$, so there is $x \in \Phi(P)$ and $x \notin N$. So, $xN \neq 1N$ in $P/N$. Moreover, we know that in $P/N$ all its nongenerator is 1( as its Frattini subgroup is only 1). So $xN$ in $P/N$ is a generator. There should exist $I/N$ (not whole $P/N$) a subgroup in $P/N$ that:
$$ \langle xN,I/N \rangle =P/N$$
In the $aN$, $a$ an arbitrary element in $P$:
$$ \langle I,x \rangle \cap \;  aN \neq \emptyset \quad \text{because we have}\; aN \; \text{in} \langle xN,I/N \rangle \text{as an element} $$
But, we have $N \subseteq I$. We have $an \in \; \langle x,I \rangle $ and $n^{-1} \in I$, Thus:
$$an.n^{-1}=a \in \; \langle x,I \rangle$$.
But, $I \neq P$ ,$x$ a nongenrator, and $ \langle x , I \rangle =P$. **Contradiction**.

My further requests:

1. I am new in using Latex every points will be a great help.
2. Is there any rules in writing mathematics' proofs? I think my writing is not organized.

Comment: About Lemma 1. Basically it's OK, but a couple of comments. (i) The assertion is true for all finite elementary abelian $p$-groups. (ii) Your proof depends on knowing such a group is a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$ - which is true, but maybe you should say why, it helps check how "deep" the proof is.

Comment: Notation: personally I find it very hard to read stuff about $p$-groups where $p$ is also used as the name of an element of the group. Also I find it hard to read stuff about groups where $I$ is used for a non-trivial subgroup - my mind says "identity". It doesn't make your proof wrong, but (in my opinion) less easy to read.

Comment: Basically I think your proof works, although I think it can be simplified a bit.

Comment: Thank You, I added your comments. I hope it is better and easier to read now.

Comment: Use `$\langle \Bbb Z\rangle$` for $\langle \Bbb Z\rangle$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I thought elementary abelian $p$-groups were defined as being direct products of cyclic groups of order $p$.

Comment: Not sure if your groups are meant to be finite, but if that is the case, then $\Phi(G)=G'G^p$ for a $p$-group $G$. This provides a straightforward proof of your statement.

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought they were defined as abelian of exponent $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be this:
In finite $p$-groups, $\Phi(G)=G'G^{p}$, where $G^{p}=\langle g^{p}\mid g\in G \rangle$. Now as both $G'$ and $G^{p}$ are subgroups of $N$, we get the result.